# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < when calling webservice from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, web-services

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var userName = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        authenticate(userName, password);
    });
 });

 function authenticate(userName, password) {
    var serviceurl = "amismobilesapps/amismobileservices.asmx?op=getUserAuthentication";
    var postdata = JSON.stringify({
        "userName": JSON.stringify($("#username").val()),
        "password": JSON.stringify($("#password").val())
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: serviceurl,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "text/javascript;charset=utf-8",
        data: postdata,
        dataType: 'JSONP',
        async: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        jsonp: 'callback',
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert('Web service call succeeded.  ' + msg.d);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('ERROR has occurred!');
            alert(JSON.stringify(error))
        }
    })
 }
```

MY WEBSERVICE IS:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://apps.avineonindia.com/")][WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo =WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]// [ToolboxItem(false)[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)][System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class amismobileservices : System.Web.Services.WebService
{ 
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AMISTEST"].ToString());

    [WebMethod]
    [System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)] 
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public bool getUserAuthentication(string UserName, string pwd)
    { 
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select  * from EMPLOYEE_MAS where Login_name='" + UserName + "' and password='" + pwd + "'", con);
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        if (n >= 1)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var postdata = JSON.stringify({
    "userName": $("#username").val(), //You don't need to use JSON.stringify here
    "password": $("#password").val()
});
```

instead of

```
var postdata = JSON.stringify({
    "userName": JSON.stringify($("#username").val()),
    "password": JSON.stringify($("#password").val())
});
```

Also, As you are passing  `userName, password` as arguments use them directly. like

```
var postdata = JSON.stringify({
    "userName": userName, 
    "password": password
});
```

Comment: @user3349997 try with `var serviceurl = "amismobilesapps/amismobileservices.asmx/getUserAuthentication"`

Comment: hi changed the data in ajax to data: {UserName: userName, pwd: password}, and service url to var serviceurl = "amismobilesapps/amismobileservices.asmx/getUserAuthentication". values are passing to webservice but still getting the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < . checking it in chrome i can see that webservice is returning false on unsucesful login and viceversa

Comment: my webservice reusult is in xml format.. <boolean xmlns=".../">false</boolean> guess its xml format is the problem here.. please help me out

Answer (score 0):

if u want to call webservice via ajax you need to write direct method name after your webservice name ...
for `e.g :webservice.asmx/methodname`

```
     function authenticate(userName, password) {
//change  url here 
        var serviceurl = "amismobilesapps/amismobileservices.asmx/getUserAuthentication";
        var postdata = JSON.stringify({
            "userName": JSON.stringify($("#username").val()),
            "password": JSON.stringify($("#password").val())
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: serviceurl,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "text/javascript;charset=utf-8",
            data: postdata,
            dataType: 'JSONP',
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            jsonp: 'callback',
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
            success: function (msg) {
                alert('Web service call succeeded.  ' + msg.d);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('ERROR has occurred!');
                alert(JSON.stringify(error))
            }
        })
     }
```

Comment: getting 500 (Internal Server Error) when tried using amismobilesapps/amismobileservices.asmx/getUserAuthentication